# "auto" keyword: How to customize it?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto

Title is vague, I know. Consider this:

```
template<typename T>
using Ref = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template<typename T>
using StrongRef = std::shared_ptr<T>&;

struct Person {
    std::string m_name;
    Person(const std::string& l_name) : m_name(l_name) {}
};

class Container{
    Ref<Person> m_person;
public:
    People(const std::string& l_name) {
        m_person = std::make_shared<Person>(l_name);
    }

    ~People() {}

    StrongRef<Person> GetPerson() { return m_person; } //returning a ref to a shared 
                                     //pointer, so it doesn't increase the use_count
};

int main(){
Container container("Pedro");
/*Here lies my problem. The auto keyword is presuming a shared_ptr, not a shared_ptr&*/
auto person = container.GetPerson(); 
/*I want it auto keyword to be StrongRef<Person> not std::shared_ptr<Person>*/
}
```

Is there a way for my auto keyword to be a StrongRef instead of deducing std::shared_ptr?

Comment: `StrongRef` is a weird name for what you want, which appears to be a [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `auto` you want a reference like

```
auto& person = container.GetPerson();
```

This does have one drawback though as if `GetPerson` changes to return by value, then you are trying to bind an lvalue reference to an rvalue and that will result in a compiler error.

To get around this, you can use a forwarding reference like

```
auto&& person = container.GetPerson();
```

Now, if `container.GetPerson()` return an rvalue, `person` will be an rvalue reference and it will extend the lifetime of the temporary object to match the lifetime of `person`.

If `container.GetPerson()` returns an lvalue, then `person` will be a plain old lvalue reference to the returned object just like if you had used `auto&` instead.

Comment: Bump. I suspect `decltype(auto)` will also do what the OP seems to want.

Comment: @NathanOliver I found a way around it. I posted it

Comment: @WhozCraig Neat, I thought that only worked as a return type.  I never tried to use it in a type declaration before.  I think I still prefer `auto&&` here just because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

@NathanOliver I got it to work in this way:

instead of

```
template <typename T>
using StrongRef = std::shared_ptr<T>&;
```

I'm using

```
template <typename T>
using StrongRef = std::shared_ptr<T>&&;
```

And when I return m_person I just cast it to StrongRef

```
StrongRef<Person> GetPerson() { return (StrongRef<Person>)m_person; }
```

Now my auto keyword will be a reference to it. Therefore, not increasing the count:

```
int main() {
    People people("Pedro");
    
    auto person = people.GetPerson();


    if (person) {
        std::cout << person.use_count() << "\n"; //Remains 1
        std::cout << person->m_name << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's incorrect. person from people.GetPerson() is difference from people.m_person.

Comment: @long.kl Your're right. The goal I'm trying to achieve is not having to write auto& person = people.GetPerson() nor StrongRef<Person> person = people.GetPerson(); I just wanted the auto keyword to be deduced as a StrongRef but it seems there's no way around it. Shame

Comment: it's no way to do. reference(&) is removed in case of auto (only) deduction. it's a rule.

Comment: @PedroSarmento `auto` will **never** deduce a reference type.